# Scikit-learn in my requirements.txt & it installs successfully, but I still get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm creating a Python site in Virtual Studio. In one of my views I have:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```

So naturally, I have a requirements.txt for creating a virtual env:

```
asgiref==3.3.1
Django==3.1.5
numpy==1.19.5
pandas==1.2.1
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.5
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
wheel==0.36.2
scikit-learn==0.24.1
```

It appears to install successfully:

```
Successfully installed Django-3.1.5 asgiref-3.3.1 joblib-1.0.0 numpy-1.19.5 pandas-1.2.1 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pytz-2020.5 scikit-learn-0.24.1 scipy-1.6.0 six-1.15.0 sqlparse-0.4.1 threadpoolctl-2.1.0 wheel-0.36.2`
```

But when I migrate, I get:

```
"views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

I can't figure out for the life of me why it's saying that there's no module named 'sklearn' when it's *right there*!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up completely uninstalling Anaconda, which I had installed in order to create Jupiter notebooks. I think the Anaconda install was clashing with the libraries Virtual Studio includes. Uninstalling Anaconda and then reinstalling just Jupiter with Pip totally worked.